# I want to change the slave address in runtime again after the first configuration of i2c SLAVE. Is this possible , I'm getting errors while doing that

Tags: embedded, esp32, i2c, esp-idf

I m working with the ESP32 and using ESP-IDF for programming the firmware of this system.

Initially i configured the I2C slave device with address , lets say 0x0A .Then after in runtime code execution I wrote a code for reconfiguration of the I2C slave this time i used different address lets say for 0x0B  for configuration of the i2c slave . This time I'm getting error ----- i2c: i2c driver install error . I think I could not configure the slave device twice in single code execution or maybe I don'n know exactly how to do it in proper way. So can anyone help me with it.

Initially I'am trying to only reconfigure the slave device in runtime for multiple addresses. If it works then I'll have to control this action with master and master will send the different Slave address to overwrite the current address of slave.

Comment: Your problem is unclear without code.  How are you changing the address? Looking at the API, you should tear down the old slave with `i2c_del_slave_device` before instantiating a new device with the new address with `i2c_new_slave_device`.

Comment: Thank you @Clifford for replying my question. Actually you answered the question without the proper code. Sorry i forgot to provide the code . Actually after posting the question here I tried the method like exactly you said in your comment. Before configuring the slave once again i deleted the previous configuration and then reconfigured the I2C slave ,  this time it worked and slave got reconfigured onto the new address.   ESP-IDF i2c driver API has this function ---"i2c_driver_delete()"  for deleting the I2c configuration .

Comment: `i2c_driver_delete()` is part of the deprecated legacy i2c.h API.  I would advise against using that for new code.  Not least because it is not documented at https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/i2c.html#_CPPv418i2c_slave_config_t. It is also why you really should post your code, if only to clarify what API you are using.  Unless you fix the question, it cannot reasonably be answered, so offers no community benefit, so will likely get deleted.